# Lambda@Edge set up cache behaviour issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudfront

I'm setting up Lambda@Edge for the first time and can't seem to enter a value for the "Cache Behaviour" dropdown. Has anyone experienced and overcome this issue?

[image: CloudFront set up error]

Comment: This seems like it *might* be an unhandled permissions error... does your user have permission to perform all CloudFront operations? (e.g. `cloudfront:*` IAM actions) on all resources?

Comment: Yes, I'm logged in as the admin on the account when I get this error...

Comment: Have you found anything?  I have discovered that one of my newest AWS accounts exhibits exactly this same behavior, whether I use an IAM user or root credentials.  I have a request open with AWS support and will report back on what I find.

Comment: The issue is to do with permissions, specifically Lambda's permissions to manage CloudFront. After bumbling around AWS's interface I ended up solving the issue by using terreform.io - check out https://read.acloud.guru/supercharging-a-static-site-with-lambda-edge-da5a1314238b.

Comment: It does seem to be permissions-related, somehow, but [I'm reasonably familiar with Lambda@Edge](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A1695906+lambda+edge) and I have this problem on only one AWS account -- the newest.   Previously, the console may have thrown an error that was intuitive enough that I was able to correct the issue without giving it much thought... but I don't remember anything similar to this.  If it's permissions-related, the console should show something... not throw a JS exception.

Comment: I've seen a couple of examples of this now, anther example is deleting a replicate lambda function. Seems they've rushed their QA on Lambda@Edge!

Answer (score 1):

I don't see the JS error in the console. However, the solution that worked for me was to select the distribution (even though it looked like it was auto-selected as it is the only distribution I have currently). Once I did that, then the cache behaviors appeared and I could select them and proceed.

Comment: Seems to be a bug in their site, your answer helped me.